# How do I use foldLeft inline (without placeholders and without having to separately define the op method)

Tags: scala

I'm attempting to use a one-liner for the fold left code below. I keep hitting weird errors blocking me from doing so. Here's a snippet capturing the essences of the problem domain:

```
  val contentByName: Map[String, Set[String]] =
    Map(
        ("idsFromDb1" -> Set("1", "2", "3"))
      , ("idsFromDb2" -> Set("2", "3", "6", "7"))
      , ("idsFromDb3" -> Set("4", "5", "6", "9", "10"))
    )
  def foldOp(x: Set[String], y: (String, Set[String])): Set[String] =
    if (y._2.filter(_.size != 1).size == 0) x ++ y._2 else x
  val all0 = contentByName.foldLeft(Set[String]())(foldOp)
  val all1 = contentByName.foldLeft(Set[String]())((x: Set[String], y: (String, Set[String]))) => if (y._2.filter(_.size != 1).size == 0) x ++ y._2 else x)
```

I would like to avoid defining the method `foldOp()` if possible, and just inline it. However, I have tried all sorts of variations and have not been successful. For example, the  `all1` line shows the following errors (ScalaIDE in Eclipse in Scala Worksheet):

- ';' expected but ')' found.
- not found: value x
- not found: value x
- not found: value x
- not a legal formal parameter

I googled and searched StackOverflow explicitly (I found it pretty difficult figure out how to search for this). I didn't find anything So, any assistance is greatly appreciated, including identifying this as a duplicate and pointing me to it (which might give me an understanding how to better search in the future). Thank you.

**UPDATE:**
Turns out I had an extra close parenthesis in my `all1` case just prior to the `=>`. I almost always build these kinds of constructions up on multiple lines, and didn't in this case. Grrr.

Additionally, I learned about a new approach, "case", to this from fotNelton. So, this was still very productive for me.

Comment: Do you really mean "implement" and not "use"? You are not implementing foldLeft algorithm in your example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
val contentByName: Map[String, Set[String]] =
  Map(
    "idsFromDb1" -> Set("1", "2", "3"),
    "idsFromDb2" -> Set("2", "3", "6", "7"),
    "idsFromDb3" -> Set("4", "5", "6", "9", "10")
  )

contentByName.foldLeft(Set.empty[String]) { case (acc, (key, value)) =>
  if (acc.size == 1) acc else acc ++ value
}
```

Note that I'm using pattern match syntax for the "inline" method (better call it anonymous function), because that makes understanding the fold so much easier.

**EDIT**: Meanwhile, OP has changed the semantics of the fold, but that shouldn't affect the methodology here.

Comment: And because there is no other way... At least I could not find one last I tried.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know you could use "case" like this. In fact, it's a wee bit confusing as there is no corresponding "match". Where do I find documentation about using case this way? And, what if I was using my own non-case classes ?

Comment: @Basilevs: How about `contentByName.foldLeft(Set.empty[String]) ( (acc: Set[String], kv: (String, Set[String])) => if (acc.size == 1) acc else acc ++ kv._2 )`

Comment: @Basilevs I changed the foldOp implementation to make it useful. You might try that.

Comment: @chaotic3quilibrium still the same

Comment: @chaotic3quilibirum: There's no need to use case classes. Pattern matching works for all sorts of things in Scala. I would recommend looking at the corresponding sections in the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf).

Comment: @fotNelton Looks like your second solution works, too. I just had an extra parenthesis in my all1 case). ARGH! If you will expand your answer to include your second solution, I will mark it as accepted. Tysvm

Comment: @chaotic3quilibrium Also note that the parens around the tuples aren't needed (look at the initialization of the `Map` in the above code).

Comment: @fotNelton Is the way you are using case imply some sort or match; i.e. method_parameters match { case (acc, (key, value)) => ...}?

Comment: @chaotic3quilibrium Whenever you have a function from `A` to `B`, you can pattern match on the `A`, although that depends on the declaration style. Compare `def isOdd(x: Int): Boolean` to `val isOdd: Int => Boolean`. Don't get confused by the `val`, you could use `def` here (strictly it's not the same, but that doesn't matter here). Anyway, the latter case allows you to use pattern match syntax, the former requires you to use `match` explicitly.